# PropertyKeyInteger must be set as String. Why?

Tags: java, types, properties, nullpointerexception

I'm testing some part of code but I found a strange behaviour of setting properties in java. I'm setting some fake properties for JUnit testing. Problem is with property PARTNER_ID, which should be according definition Integer value, but when I'm setting it with method put I have to set it as String, otherwise I get null pointer exception. 
There are some me important parts of code which will say more than words:

```
import java.util.Properties;
//definition of properties    
public interface PropertyKeys  {

 public static final PropertyKeyInteger PARTNER_ID = new PropertyKeyInteger(
      "partnerId",null);
}

//fake set of the properties for mock
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("partnerId","102"); //this works
// properties.put("partnerId",102); // this ends with null pointer on PropertyKeys.PARTNER_ID.getProperty(properties)  

//this is how its called in some method
PropertyKeys.PARTNER_ID.getProperty(properties)
```

Question is: Why it allow me only set expected integer value property as String and with Integer it fails with null pointer on null pointer exception?

Comment: "PARTNER_ID = new PropertyKeyInteger" ==> what is PropertyKeyInteger  ? do you have the code?

Comment: @user1097772 Can you post your PropertyKeyIntegerClass?